# Docker Linux network topology using route tables and arp

Tags: docker, linux-networking, route, arp

I'm working with a network of docker containers. C1's routing table is below, it's default gateway `172.17.0.1` is the docker bridge.  It's eth1 interface is connected to eth2 in C2 and it routes all destinations with a prefix of 192.1 to eth2 in C2.

[image]

```
Dest          Gateway       Genmask          Iface
default       172.17.0.1     0.0.0.0          eth0
192.1.0.0     0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0      eth1
```

C2's routing table is below. It is connected to C3 between eth3 on C2 and eth4 on C3.

```
Dest          Gateway       Genmask          Iface
192.1.2.0     192.1.2.1     255.255.254.0     eth3
```

I'm able to ping C2 from C1 using `ping 192.1.1.2`, however I cannot ping C3 from C1 using `ping 192.1.2.2`.  When I try to ping C3, C1 sends out an ARP query looking for C3's Mac address which is only received by C2, and fails.  I can make the ping to C3 succeed if I manually update C1's ARP table and give it the Mac address of eth2 in C2 for `192.1.2.2`.

I believe I could also make this work by modifying C1's route table so it is on a different subnet then C3 and uses C2 as its default gateway.  This way it wants the MAC address of C2 to ping C3.

```
Dest          Gateway       Genmask          Iface
default       192.1.1.2      0.0.0.0          eth1
192.1.2.0     0.0.0.0        255.255.254.0    eth1
```

However I've been lead to believe that it should be possible to ping C3 from C1 by only modifying C2's route table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `proxy-arp` functionality. When the proxy-arp is enabled on C2, it will answer the ARP requests with own MAC address in the ARP Reply. This is what you want.

To enable the proxy arp on `eth0` interface of C2, you need run

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.proxy_arp=1
```

To enable on all interfaces run:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1
```

To make this change permanent, you should edit the sysctl settings file.